# Is there an English translation of Bernard Vitrac's annotated edition of Euclid's Elements?

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry

I was reading Heath's annotated edition of Euclid's Elements, and in the beginning, I read that Bernard Vitrac has an extensively annotated edition of Euclid's Elements in several volumes in French. I was wondering if someone can show me an English translation of the volumes, if one exists. I would be very grateful, as I like to read as much mathematics as I can.